# Automatically keep table of contents up to date?

Tags: microsoft-word

In MS Word if you have a document's TOC built up out of heading styles, you always have to click in the TOC and hit F9 to get it to rebuild it after you've edited the document.

When you do this, it shows:

[image]

**Is there some way to avoid this entirely and just have it keep the TOC up to date without any intervention?**

Failing that, can you at least avoid this dialog? I'd prefer it to always update the entire table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To update the entire TOC immediately, you need VBA and to use this command:

```
ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Update
```

You may also avoid the VBA editor and create a VBA macro by recording the user actions
you listed in the post,
then perhaps create for it a button on the Quick Access Toolbar or the Ribbon.

See
[Word macros: Three examples to automate your documents](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2952126/software-productivity/word-macros-three-examples-to-automate-your-documents.html).

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that Word must go through and locate all the various heading levels and determine their page numbers.  This requires application resources and, if you're working on a large document, this updating could affect performance or cause Word to crash.  So, constantly updating the TOC is not a desirable behavior.  The VBA recommended in harrymc's answer will certainly do the trick.  If you don't want to use a macro, then use Ctrl+A to select the entire document, then F9 to update all fields.  You'll get the same prompt (Update entire table / Update page numbers only) for each TOC field within the selection.

If you have Word 2016, the default setting is to "Update fields before printing."  You can turn this feature on or off in Options | Display | Printing Options.